# Properly loading webshims / modernizr with requirejs?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, modernizr, webshim

I have modernizr / pollyfiller included at the top of my index.html file, and in my main.js:

```
require.config({
    paths : {
    'jquery' : 'lib/jquery-1.10.2.min',
    'jqdate' : 'lib/jquery.dateFormat-1.0',
    'webshims' : 'lib/polyfiller'
},
shim : {
    'lib/underscore' : {
        exports : '_'
    },
    'lib/backbone' : {
        deps : ["lib/underscore", "jquery"],
        exports : 'Backbone'
    },
    "modernizr" : {
        deps : ["jquery"],
        exports : "modernizr"
    },
    "webshims" : {
        deps : [ "jquery", "lib/modernizr-custom"],
        exports: "webshims"
    }
}
});
var router, vent;

    require(["jquery", "lib/underscore", "lib/backbone", "app", "lib/modernizr-custom", "webshims"], function($, _, Backbone, Router, modernizr, webshims) {

$(function() {
    $.webshims.setOptions('forms forms-ext', {
        replaceUI : false,
        waitReady : false
    });

    $.webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');

    router = new Router();
    vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
    $.expr.cacheLength = 1;

    Backbone.history.start({

    });
});
});
```

This will generally load fine, however, sometimes it looks like webshims is not defined by the time I try to call:

```
    $.webshims.setOptions('forms forms-ext', {
        replaceUI : false,
        waitReady : false
    });

    $.webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
```

and I get the error: TypeError: $.webshims is undefined

Is there a better way to load this?

**edit**
So, I updated the script like you said, and had to capitalize Webshims in the paths and shim definition.  It loads fine but now I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

in Chrome and

```
SyntaxError: syntax error


<!DOCTYPE html>
```

in firefox

Comment: It is unclear to me why you had to capitalize webshim. Also, you've edited your question to show the changes but the ``require`` call still shows webshim in lowercase in the requirements array. The error you are now reporting looks like something is trying to load an HTML file as JS code. It is unclear to me whether this is related at all to the RequireJS problem you had or *that* problem has been solved and now you have run into *another* problem.

Comment: When using the lowercase webshims, here is what happens:  Error: Load timeout for modules: lib/polyfiller http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

Comment: I would suggest using whatever debugging facility you have at your disposal to check the network queries from your browser to your server. That's how I've always resolved timeout problems.

Comment: I have updated to reflect your suggestions.  I am using local host and see the polyfiller.js loading. Yet it still times out.

Comment: Does polyfiller.js actually contain JS code? And does it set a global named ``webshims``? If not, that could be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated Answer

Alexander Farkas pointed out in a comment that [polyfiller defines itself as `"polyfiller"`](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/gh-pages/src/polyfiller.js#L8) like this:

```
define('polyfiller', ['jquery'], factory);
```

So:

1. No shim should be required to load polyfiller.js.
2. The module defined by `polyfiller.js` should *always* be referred to as `"polyfiller"`. So there has to be a `paths` setting that maps the module name `polyfiller` to the actual path of the `polyfiller.js` file.

So the original config should be modified to remove the `"webshims"` shim, then the `paths` setting `"webshims": "lib/polyfiller"` should become `"polyfiller": "lib/polyfiller"` and the require call should be:

```
require(["jquery", "lib/underscore", "lib/backbone", "app", "lib/modernizr-custom", "polyfiller"], function($, _, Backbone, Router, modernizr) {
```

I've dropped the last variable from the function's parameters because there's no need to pass the module value since the `polyfiller.js` file registers itself as `$.webshims`.

This is similar to how jQuery defines itself as `"jquery"` (it needs no shim and is always called `"jquery"`).

#### Original Answer

Change your `require` call so that you require `"webshims"` instead of `"lib/polyfiller"`:

```
require(["jquery", "lib/underscore", "lib/backbone", "app", "lib/modernizr-custom", "webshims"], ...
```

The code in your question shows you've set the `paths` configuration option so that the module name `"webshims"` resolves to `"lib/polyfiller"`, and created what looks like a sensible shim for it. However, when you require the `webshims` module you refer to it as `"lib/polyfiller"`. RequireJS does not do a reverse resolution to figure out that `"lib/polyfiller"` is `"webshims"`.

Alternatively, you could drop the `"webshims"` name from `paths` and rename the shim so that it is set for `"lib/polyfiller"`. However, I consider it to be a better practice to refer to 3rd party libraries by one-word names throughout an application rather than have paths for them. So "jquery", "bootstrap", "underscore", and "webshims" etc. rather than "lib/...".

Comment: It looks like the error is being cause by it trying to load webshims.js, and there is a 302 error.  After changing the code as I did above, shouldn't it be looking for the lib/polyfiller.js when I reference webshims in require?

Comment: it is looking for webshims.js, which doesn't exist

Comment: You changed "webshims" to "Webshims" *everywhere* except in your ``require`` call. It still reads "webshims" there (all lowercase). If you have "Webshims" in your config and "webshims" in your require, then RequireJS will look for "webshims" first and then "webshims.js" because "Webshims" != "webshims".

Comment: Yes.  Which at least seemed to resolve to the correct file.  Your suggestions created a timeout.  Thank you for help though.

Comment: Don't know wether this changes something, but webshims polyfill.js (the file, which should be included) already registers itself as polyfill (see: https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/gh-pages/src/polyfiller.js#L8)

Comment: @alexanderfarkas Thanks. Yes, this is absolutely crucial. I'm going to update my answer. I responded from the POV of someone who uses RequireJS for a 50-module app so I saw a RequireJS problem but I did not know that there was also a problem on that end.

Comment: Your answer makes sense.  I think the reason it was still working when it was looking for webshims.js, is because the polyfiller.js was still being loaded, so $.webshims would still work.  I guess my question then is  how would I update from the global usage of the $.webshims, to make use of the polyfill definition?

Comment: @user3000116 updated the answer with more details, starting with "So the original config..."

Comment: This works! thanks.  the one thing is, that including it in the require call causes the same error as before (timing out looking for js/polyfill.js instead of lib/polyfill), but it leaving it out works fine.